# When would Least Square Estimate equals Maximum Likelihood Estimation?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, optimization

Under what situations, MLE(Maximum Likelihood Estimation) would equal to LSE(Least Square Estimate)?

I got an impression that under norm 2, MLE and LSE is equal.

For example the question $min || y- Ax ||_{2}$ equals doing MLE estimation of parameter A  for $y=Ax+\varepsilon$ where $x$ and $\varepsilon$  is normal.

However, is that generally true that the minimization problem under L2 norm is the same as maximum likelihood estimation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it would help if you could define acronyms like Least Square Estimator (LSE),  Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) and also add context to the question as it is unclear at present, but should be easy to cleanup. Regards

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot for your reminding Amzoti!

Answer (score 0):

They both collide if the noise is AWGN.

Probably it can be generalized to any white noise with distribution defined be Euclidean Distance of the variable from the mean.